# Define in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I was trying to run this command on drracket:

```
(define #t #f)
```

and I get the following error messege:

```
define: bad syntax in: #t
```

I want to know what's the reason for that error, and why I can do: `(define + 12)` and not this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a stupid question, probably, but _why would you want to do this_? D-:

Answer (score 4):

The [syntax of `define`](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-8.html#%_sec_5.2) is:

```
(define <variable> <expression>)
```

[A variable is a special kind of identifier](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-6.html#%_sec_3.1), and [the format of identifiers is described here](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-5.html#%_sec_2.1). As you can see from the description, `#t` (and more generally, anything that starts with a `#`) is not an identifier.

Comment: It is actually `(define <identifier> <expression>)` formally in the R7RS Specfication.

Comment: @GoZoner See section 5.3 (page 25) in R7RS. It still uses `<variable>`. (I do agree that it actually does boil down to an `<identifier>`, and section 7.1.6 (page 64) says the same thing.)

Comment: Nice.  Syntactically it is an `<identifier>`; semantically it is a `<variable>` (identifier bound to a location, non-syntax).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`define` expects an identifier as it's first argument. In this case you are supplying `#t` which evaluates to the boolean value true. Hence the `bad syntax` error message.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment to keltar, please don't confuse symbol with identifier. `define` expects an identifier, not a symbol. For example, you cannot do `(define (string->symbol "foo") 'bar)`, or even `(define 'foo 'bar)` for that matter.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young - Good point, I updated my answer. That said, `(define 'foo 'bar)` actually does evaluate in all the schemes I tested: chicken, bigloo, chibi, husk. But that is just a technicality because it expands to an expression containing the identifier `quote`.

Answer (score -2):

First argument to `define` must be a symbol. `+` is a symbol. `foo` is a symbol. `#t` is #t, not a symbol. `1` is not a symbol.

Comment: s/symbol/identifier/g

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young scheme have word 'symbol' in specification, so i stick to that

Comment: Please see: [the syntax of definitions](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-8.html#%_sec_5.2) and [what a variable is](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-6.html#%_sec_3.1). The external form for an identifier is indeed a symbol, but in the actual code, an identifier and a symbol are very different things. In the same way, the external form for the expression `(+ 3 4)` is a list, but when running the code, obviously it doesn't evaluate to a list.

Comment: To further reinforce my point that `define` wants an identifier and not a symbol, this is invalid: `(define (string->symbol "foo") 'bar)`. Heck, even `(define 'foo 'bar)` is invalid.